# Method findPreference always returning null

Tags: android

The issue I am having is that the method `findPreference` is always returning `null`. I have checked multiple times whether the key (i.e. "`pref_about`") is correct, and it is.

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
    initPreferences();
}

private void initPreferences() {
    Preference myPref = findPreference("pref_about");
    myPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(TAG, "btn_about");
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

The corresponding XML file is:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Preference android:title="About" android:key="pref_about "/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Only issue which could cause this is if you use nested PreferenceScreens and each screen opens a fragment, the findPreference may fail because the nested fragment might not contain the preferences you look for with findPreference.